# Calculate a row rank in efficient manner

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ranking, rank

I have the following table with approximately 10M data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_site_visit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `siteURL` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `userHash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Also `siteURL, userUID, timestamp` has indexes.

Now, I want to calculate the rank of a site based on the above data but in fast and efficient manner. I wrote the following query but the rank is not correct and it is also takes around `40~60sec` to calculate the rank:

```
SET @prevRank := -1, @rankCounter := 0;

SELECT siteURL, siteRank FROM ( 
    SELECT *, @rankCounter := IF(@prevRank = visitCount, @rankCounter, @rankCounter + 1) AS siteRank, @prevRank := visitCount AS dummyRank FROM (
        SELECT siteURL, COUNT(1) AS visitCount
        FROM tbl_site_visit
        GROUP BY siteURL
        ORDER BY visitCount DESC
    ) coreTable
) rankedTable
WHERE rankedTable.siteURL = "www.google.com"
LIMIT 1;
```

Any ideas to how solve this problem or is there any statistical formula to calculate the rank?

Answer (score 0):

One mistake you have is that you are calculating the rank for all sites and then select the result of that site.

You should instead calculate the rank only for that site only.

```
SET @prevRank := -1, @rankCounter := 0;

SELECT siteURL, siteRank FROM ( 
    SELECT *, @rankCounter := IF(@prevRank = visitCount, @rankCounter, @rankCounter + 1) AS appRank, @prevRank := visitCount AS dummyRank FROM (
        SELECT siteURL, COUNT(1) AS visitCount
        FROM tbl_site_visit WHERE siteURL = "www.google.com"
        GROUP BY siteURL
        ORDER BY visitCount DESC
    ) coreTable
) rankedTable
```

This should calculate the rank only for 'www.google.com' and return it's data. Some of the outer `SELECT`s can be removed but depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: No, this way isn't true, the calculated rank is 1 by this method while the actual rank is 4!

Comment: So your rank value should be calculated in relation to other sites?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  @rank := @rank+1 AS rank, siteURL, visitCount
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  @rank := 0 ) AS z
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  siteURL, COUNT(*) AS visitCount
            FROM  tbl_site_visit
            GROUP BY  siteURL 
      ) AS x
    ORDER BY  visitCount DESC;
```